# React multiple subdomain auth with jwt

Tags: reactjs, authentication, jwt, subdomain

We want develop few different services (React Apps) with the same users database and Rest API.
Some users might have access to APP 1, some for APP 2, some for both depends on their role.

- We decided to go on multiple subdomain apps method.
- We want SSO so only one page/app to authenticate all the apps and not a local login component for each app. using JWT mechanism in our backend.

### STRUCTURE:

[image]

---

### AUTH FLOW:

[image]

#### There are two main problems in this flow which are marked as 1 and 2:

1. Lets say i go to the login app and log in, getting accestoken from the backend. 
   How do i deliver the token to app1.company.com? should react login APP redirect with token in url param?

   - local storage is subdomain scoped.
   - iframe has problems with Safari.
   - I don't wanna save jwt in cookies for now because the flask REST can serve non-browser retailed clients.

2. Lets say the user want to go to app2. if we aren't able to share the token from app1 with iframes or any other method, then this app should be redirected to login and make the process again as app1, which is fine for us. 
   But is this really the way? if token is invalid anymore and we get Error from backend, should we redirect to the login app in the other subdomain (embed the url we wanna go back to after login success)?

   - Can i just use 3rd party Open id connect service?
   - Should i consider microfrontends approcah to make the all the "apps" on the same domain?
   - How "Attlassian" as an example handles this process?

#### What am i missing and what is the best way to solve this flow?

Comment: Hi Amit. Why do you need to share tokens between applications? Can't you just log in using an OAuth 2 flow on each page? After the first login, for example in app1.company.com you won't even need to enter the credentials on login.company.com when logging using app2.company.com page.

Comment: Hey Geroge, i did read about the OAuth 2 and OICD extension features after you comment.

Comment: So does OAuth 2 solve your problem? You can use an external provider like Auth0 if you don't feel comfortable creating a custom OAuth 2 flow by yourself. If so you the login item in your diagram would become the external provider, and all the other pages will redirect to that provider to request a token.

Comment: Yeah i have noticed now that i didn't finish my comment because we started to talk on a private chat :) i dont want my users to login with google for now, i want to be their only provider, therefore open id would be related for me only if i create my own OAuth 2 Autherntication Server which seems like an overhead. the other solution you gave me, to just leave my server as it is (JWT auth compatiable) and saving this JWT in a cookie which will make it avilable to all subdomain aswell , with just redirection seems more relevent, please correct me if im wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Lets say i go to the login app and log in, getting accestoken from the backend. How do i deliver the token to app1.company.com?

It is not a problem that login.company.com delivers the token as a parameter in the URL, because the site can verify the authenticity of the token by verifying the digital signature or with a specific endpoint in the central authentication domain. This is how openid/oauth2 does it using the "implicit" flow, although they also allows to send the token as POST, or use a 2-step flow ("authorization_code" flow)

> Lets say the user want to go to app2. if we aren't able to share the token from app1 with iframes or any other method, then this app should be redirected to login and make the process again as app1, which is fine for us. But is this really the way?

You can share the token between domains using an internal iframe, but in your case I would recommend that each domain use its own token.

> if token is invalid anymore and we get Error from backend, should we redirect to the login app in the other subdomain (embed the url we wanna go back to after login success)?

Yes, in the number 2) of your drawing, just redirect from app2.company.com to login.company.com and follow the same flow as in 1). You will need some type of cookie on login.company.com to avoid requesting credentials from the user again

> Can i just use 3rd party Open id connect service?

Yes, you can use an external OpenIdConnect service, or deploy at login.company.com an OpenIdConnect server like IdentityServer or KeyCloak

> Should i consider microfrontends approcah to make the all the "apps" on the same domain?

It is not necessary having a central authentication domain

> How "Attlassian" as an example handles this process?

I don't know exactly how Attlassian does it, but currently most web services support OpenIdConnect

Comment: So what do you think is the best and fastest approach a if i dont want to use 3rd provider for now. 
1. Develop my own Auth server with AuthLib or keycloack.
2. Save the received token in domain cookie in login.company.com so it will be available for the subdomains at redirection 
3.To redirect the sites in the frontend with the token recived via url Params.

Am  i missing a better option regarding to the fact that my server currently supports jwt auth?

Comment: "best" and "fastest" do not usually combine well. If you want a fast and easy solution, use a cookie in login site to remember user is logged, but issue a different token for each site that requests a login. If you want a long term solution use openid.

Comment: Got it.
Why should I generate a different token for each site? Cant I send the overall jwt after login and save it in cookie so any request from any app will contain the cookie with the user's common jwt token?

Openid connect means that my server will be a client with 3rd provider like Google OR to make my server the Auth server with authlib or keycloak, is that correct?
Thank you again.

Comment: Different sites usually means different scopes. Reusing the same token means you have a global scope for all of them. Maybe this is your case. // You can store the token in a cookie. Keep in mind that you will need protection against CSRF attacks. // Openid is a protocol between clients, authentication server and protected resources. You can use your own authentication server or use a third party service